# "Komm jetzt" vs "Komm schon"

Tags: phrase, informal

Is there a difference between the two phrases "komm schon" and "komm jetzt"?

While, of course, their literal translations differ, I believe they both roughly translate to "come on".

I assume they are both informal phrases. But, are there different situations to which these can be applied, or can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Komm' schon" would probably be the more fitting translation for "come on" for encouragement or prodding. "Komm' jetzt" is more like "Come *now*". An impatient mother might say that to her dawdling child.

"Komm' jetzt" on its own is quite harsh, like an order or a command. You might want to think about whether you get to order the recipient around or not ;)

As a part of a longer sentence, "komm' jetzt" is less harsh, but still somewhat pushy. You might find it in advertisements, for example:

> Komm' jetzt zu Superkauf und spare!
>
> Hurry to Superkauf now and save (a lot of money)!

or

> Kommt jetzt alle zur Kirmes!
>
> Hurry now to the carnival, everybody!

Just in case somebody wonders what the apostrophe in *komm'* means: It signifies that *komm'* is a shortened version of *komme*.